# Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:ository

Tags: android, avd-manager

When I try to run this command :

`./avdmanager create avd -n Android_TV -d 0 -k "system-images;android-29;android-tv;x86"`

getting an error :

```
 Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:ository...
```

Also, I tried running this command: `./sdkmanager list`
Giving a warning :  `Warning: Failed to find package list.`

Please help me with this as I am trying to create an Android Tv emulator on my device farm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create AVD for android in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705835/create-avd-for-android-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Hi first you need to download the image with sdkmanager

```
./sdkmanager "system-images;android-29;android-tv;x86"
```

It will download the image in "system-images" folder then you could run your command